# How many Access databases can an Access form connect to?

Tags: microsoft-access

Is it possible to have an Access form send data to or retrieve data from multiple Access databases? I want to have user-input data to be sent to a different database, due to size limitations. Can this be done?

Comment: I routinely link tables from various Access databases into one "main" Access database. The linked tables can then be used in any way you like, you can query them, create read/write forms, etc. Check this out: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tables/link_table2007.php.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to insert data from your form into kind of parallel databases.

There is no built-in process for this kind of activity, you can do it by using some complicated queries or writing macro to decide where to load.